# Flutter emulator personal keyboard does not work

Tags: dart, flutter

I created an emulator with VSCode for Flutter programming purposes, everything works great except the fact that i cannot use my own keyboard to write on TextFields, i'm forced to use the embbed keyboard of the android.

How do i allow key input from my keyboard?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify that option on the emulated device's settings if you've created the emulator using flutter with VSCode.

1. Open **Android Studio**.
2. Hover over the **Tools** section on the top bar and click **AVD Manager**
3. Find your emulated device on the list and click to **pen icon** to edit device specific settings.
4. Click to **Show Advanced Settings**.
5. Scroll down and make sure **Enable keyboard input** is ticked.

[There is also pictured version of these steps.](https://i.snipboard.io/Bxd7mP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have used an old emulator for API Level 23, which does not take keyboard input for my apk. So I have created new emulator for API Level 29, and then it works. Following is the step to install new emulator.

1. Open "Android Virtual Device Manager"
2. Create new Virtual Device.
3. When you select a system image, please choose and download the last version(API Level29) on "Virtual Device Configuration" window

Answer (score 0):

Go to emulator -> I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard.
It also works on Mac when on the emulator select: `command + K`